# Get specific transaction ID from invoice

Tags: paypal, payment, transaction

I know that I can use `order->getPayment()->getLastTransId()` to get the related transaction id from the most recently processed transaction, but it's not as specific as I'd like.

Is there a method to get the specific transaction id associated with an invoice?

Example:
Place Order -> Original Authoriztaion ID xxx1
Partial Invoice A -> Delayed Capture Transaction ID xxx2
Partial Invoice B -> Delayed Capture Transaction ID xxx3
Final Invoice C -> Delayed Capture Transaction ID xxx4

How would I get the transaction ID that is specifically related to Invoice A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question but try

```
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
      $oInvoiceCollection = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
      foreach ($oInvoiceCollection as $oInvoice) {
          $transaction_id  = $oInvoice->getTransactionId();
          // ...
      }
}
```

if you know the invoice id

```
$oInvoice = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->load($id);
$transaction_id  = $oInvoice->getTransactionId();
```